# Master Project in MSProj10 moves the dates in the subprojects

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

When I add in the subprojects to the Master Project, the date ranges are unaffected UNTIL I expand the subproject - at which point - the dates all shift to the right.  Can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you can't prevent that because the data from the subprojects is only loaded when you expand them.